# webjar GET error

Tags: javascript, maven, webjars

I am trying to include the graceful-fs webjar in my web-app. I have included the following in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars.npm</groupId>
    <artifactId>graceful-fs</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and this line

```
 <script src="/webjars/graceful-fs/2.0.3/fs.js"></script>
```

in my index.html file.

I keep on getting the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/graceful-fs/2.0.3/fs.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Any advice or idea is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That file doesn't exist for that version:
http://www.webjars.org/listfiles/org.webjars.npm/graceful-fs/2.0.3

Try: `http://localhost:8080/webjars/graceful-fs/2.0.3/graceful-fs.js`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, however I'm having the same response for graceful-fs.js too and actually with all the js files of this webjar:
GET http://localhost:8080/webjars/graceful-fs/2.0.3/graceful-fs.js

Comment: Are you having that problem for only that WebJar or all WebJars?

Comment: I've noticed that I'm having a problem with the requirejs 2.1.20 webjar as well. But for example this one works fine: webjars/elasticsearch-js/3.1.3/elasticsearch.js

Comment: First make sure that these WebJars are correctly in the running app's classpath.  There are a few different ways to check that.  But perhaps start by restarting your server.  Then you can debug the classloader to see what files are in it.  Help for that: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/